# how to I get the correct results from my code below?

Tags: sql, postgresql

the below shows me those who have made transcation above 11.98 but it shows all of their transactions even the below 11.98. I just want the ones above 11.98

```
select p.
customer_id, first_name,amount
from customer
inner join payment p on p.customer_id=customer.customer_id
where p.
customer_id in (
  select
    customer_id 
  from payment 
  group by amount,customer_id
  having min(amount) > 11.98
)
order by customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think better to use :

```
select p.customer_id, c.first_name, sum(p.amount) as amount
  from customer c
  join payment p on p.customer_id = c.customer_id
 group by p.customer_id, c.first_name
having sum(q.amount) > 11.98
 order by p.customer_id, c.first_name
```

considering every individual(first name) and customer ID combination is adjacent and unique.

But if you consider every payment seperately, then use :

```
select p.customer_id, c.first_name, p.amount
  from customer c
  join payment p on p.customer_id = c.customer_id
 where p.customer_id in (
                         select customer_id 
                           from payment 
                          group by customer_id
                         having min(amount) > 11.98
                        )
 order by p.customer_id;
```

by just removing `amount` from `group by amount,customer_id`

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple `where` clause?

```
select c.customer_id, c.first_name, p.amount
from customer c inner join
     payment p
     on p.customer_id = c.customer_id
where p.amount > 11.98
order by c.customer_id;
```

This automatically only returns customers who have an amount greater than 11.98.

If you want details for customers who *only* have amounts greater than 11.98, then use a window function so you can filter on the minimum amount per customer:

```
select c.customer_id, c.first_name, p.amount
from customer c inner join
     (select p.*,
             min(p.amount) over (partition by p.customer_id) as min_amount
      from payment p
     ) p
     on p.customer_id = c.customer_id
where min_amount > 11.98
order by c.customer_id;
```